# Why doesn't the org.springframework.boot import work but the org.springframework.web does?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to build this RESTful service example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
The `GreetingController.java` has no errors with the imports:

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

But with `Application.java` I get:
[image: source code image with errors]

I get the following error: `The import org.springframework.boot cannot be resolved.` I've added the Spring 4 library to the project with all the jars. Why does the first import work and the second doesn't? I also get no errors with the `@ComponentScan` annotation but I get an error with the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation.

Comment: You seem to not have included any Spring Boot dependencies. Are you using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: In Netbeans, the Spring Framework library doesn't seem to include spring-boot. Your IDE screenshot looks like IntelliJ - maybe look in the library to see if there is an entry for spring-boot ?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE and Maven. I have included the `pom.xml` file used on the Spring site. I looked into the jars of the Spring library. There is no spring-boot jar.

Comment: Are you using maven inside your IDE. Judging from your description you aren't and you are meddling around with manually adding jars to your project instead of using the Maven integration.

Comment: It seems to work now. I have added the dependencies in the `pom.xml` file and now I have no errors. I will try to build the project, deploy it and I will tell you the results.

Comment: I suggest you tell Eclipse that the project is a Maven project so that it uses Maven to actually grab the dependencies. There is no reason for doing it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed finally to make it work. The problem was in the `pom.xml` file that was posted on the Spring site: it needs some modifications. Here is the version I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I then proceeded to build the project with Maven, Eclipse plugin. There was a process that was occupying the 8080 port so I killed it. I ran the `.jar` I got from Maven build and it worked! Thanks guys for pointing the problem. I needed Maven to define dependencies and not manually include libraries. I think I have to learn Maven sooner or later. :)

Comment: to post above, ī'd suggest to run also maven command so everything would be fine `mvn clean install -U`. the `-U` param forces to download dependency once again even you have it in local maven repo already

Answer (score 0):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dugu.acc.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstSpringBootApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FirstSpringBootApp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>FirstSpringBootApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**it worked for me.**

Comment: it will be a better answer if you describe your code there!